# How to get current spring form session bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I have form:

```
     <form:form commandName="entity" role="form">
       <myCustomTag path="field_id" />
     </form:form>
```

How I can find out what is commandName inside my custom tag?
(MyCustomTag.tag file below)

```
     <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
     <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

     <%@ attribute name="path" required="true" rtexprvalue="true"
         description="Name of corresponding property in bean object"%>

     <div class="form-group">
         <form:label path="${path}"><spring:message code="mylabelformat_${what_to_put_here?}_${path}"/></form:label>
         <form:input path="${path}" class="form-control" placeholder="${placeholder}" />
         <form:errors class="invalid" path="${path}" />
     </div>
```

Comment: Check `nestedPath` request attribute (and use `<spring:bind>` tag to get to model object properties).

Comment: Hmm what would be spring:bind then to find out word "entity"? With ${status.expression} I can get individual field name.

Comment: I don't understand the comment question. :(

Comment: Question is what is expression to use then in my custom .tag file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use-case you can use `nestedPath` request attribute, which is being set by the `<spring:form>` tag:

```
<spring:message code="mylabelformat_${nestedPath}${path}"/>
```

The translation code would then be (for your example):

```
mylabelformat_entity.field_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The `form` attribute `commandName` is referring to a model attribute (you could use the equivalent `form` attribute `modelAttribute`). Since model attributes are just request attributes when the view is rendered, `entity` is actually just a request attribute.

In your custom tag, just get it

```
MyEntity entity = (MyEntity) request.getAttribute("entity");
```

Comment: Can I reference this somehow in .tag file? I added my example file at question post.

Comment: @user3102259 Not as far as I know.